# Curl не получается получить видео со страницы

Tags: php, curl

При открытии страницы в браузере, видео работает (ссылка на видео внутри кода).
Но при открытии через Curl, никак не хочет.

Мой код:

```
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
$url = "https://cs543502.vkuservideo.net/u131244/videos/b7f8f10e73.720.mp4";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $html;
```

Comment: По вашей ссылке 404 статус. Вконтактик даже переход по ссылкам на внешние ресурсы не дает делать без авторизации у них, а вы видео захотели получить ;)

Comment: @Visman да, уже нету, у них видимо ссылка доступна примерно час. Наверное только через их API можно.

Comment: Оказывается нужно просто через плеер запускать видео, тогда все работает. Вопрос решен.